# I have a question about the single responsibility principle in state management in Flutter's Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, object, state, riverpod

Suppose you have code that manages bool type values like the following: (Made with Riverpod)

```dart
final isPremiumProvider = NotifierProvider<IsPremiumNotifier, bool>(() {
  return IsPremiumNotifier();
});

class IsPremiumNotifier extends Notifier<bool> {
  @override
  bool build() {
    return _fetchIsPremium();
  }

  void upgrade() {
    state = state.copyWith(isPremium: true);
    _saveIsPremium();
  }

  void downgrade() {
    state = state.copyWith(isPremium: false);
    _saveIsPremium();
  }

/*
_saveIsPremium() and _fetchIsPremium() may be different classes.
Is it okay to execute a method that saves locally with upgrade() or downgrade()? That's what I'm asking.
*/
  void _saveIsPremium() {
    /* Store managed state locally */
  }

 bool _fetchIsPremium() {
    /* Processing to retrieve from local */
  }
}
```

At this time, `upgrade()` and `downgrade()` involve two processes: changing the managed state and calling a method that saves the state locally. I think this goes against the Single Responsibility Principle, but values that are supposed to be stored locally are always synced with the data on the app side.

In cases like this, is it okay to code against the Single Responsibility Principle?
please tell me your opinion.

Comment: This question may not be related to the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: When you consider the local service as "manage a cache for a remote value", it's doing only one thing.

Comment: And a separate piece of advice.... don't use bools like that.  You'll get deep into some other code and forget which true vs false means.  Use an enum with names for the states.  That way, if you have a third state, you can just add it to the enum and fix up switches, rather than a lot of difficult locating bools.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I named it `is⚪︎⚪︎` because I can tell that it is a bool by naming it `is⚪︎⚪︎`.

Comment: Is that no good?

Comment: An "is" name helps, and if you're stuck with a bool, that's a good thing.  But there's no room for expansion.  Enums are free.  Use them. :)  Also, by creating a separate type you can't confuse this bool with that bool or accidentally assign them incorrectly.

Comment: I see!
❌`bool isPremium`
⭕️
`enum UserType {
  'premium',
  'normal',
}
`
It means that it is better to
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As clearly noted in the comments to your question, it is better to use an enum of the form instead of bool:

```dart
enum Tariff { free, premium }
```

Further, your class is engaged in only one business logic - it controls the current tariff. And he may well keep this tariff, if he sees fit. This is considered normal.

However, I would be careful not to implicitly use dependencies, whether it's accessing local storage or another service/repository. A good option would be to immediately indicate these dependencies next to the class definition:

```dart
// use tear-off
final tariffProvider = NotifierProvider<TariffNotifier, Tariff>(IsPremiumNotifier.new);

class TariffNotifier extends Notifier<Tariff> {

  late final localStorage;

  @override
  bool build() {
    // in this method, you can track other providers
    localStorage = ref.watch(localStorageProvider);
    return _fetchIsPremium();
  }

  void upgrade() {
    state = Tariff.premium;
    _save();
  }

  void downgrade() {
    state = Tariff.free;
    _save();
  }

  void _save() {
    localStorage.setTariff(state);
  }

 Tariff _fetchIsPremium() {
    return localStorage.getTariff();
  }
}
```

This allows you to instantly see all the dependencies (and capabilities) of a given class.